# ¿Por qué convierte 021 a un número diferente del que debería?

Tags: javascript

¿Por qué el resultado es 15?

Estoy cambiando la base de `21` en octal a decimal. Sin embargo, el valor debería ser `17`, pero me devuelve `15` y no entiendo por qué.

```js
console.log(parseInt(021, 8)); // retorna : 15 en vez de 17
```

Comment: en la respuesta que te dieron dice que el segundo parametro especifica el sistema numerico a usar

Comment: @JackNavaRow no es un duplicado, por favor revisa mi respuesta al respecto

Comment: @Ruslan estos son los casos que ameritan una buena edición que modifique el título de la pregunta y el contenido, para que quede claro qué es lo que están preguntando, que se entienda la diferencia en que no están preguntando sobre una conversión de tipos, y cuál es el problema específico, haciendo además que puedan encontrarse en una búsqueda.

Answer (score 8):

Al utilizar el 0 al inicio se está especificando que es un número octal de base 8), por lo cual:

> 21 en octal es igual a 8 * 2 + 1 = 17

Entonces es como si hicieras

```js
console.log(parseInt(17, 8))
```

Algo de documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt

Answer (score 3):

Lo que pasa es que la notación para un número en octal consiste en ponerle un cero a la izquierda, así que no estás convirtiendo el número 21 decimal, sino 21 octal que es 17 en decimal, pero 17 decimal es 15 en octal, por eso es que obtienes 15.

He aquí la demostración:

```js
console.log(parseInt(021, 8)); // retorna : 15
console.log(parseInt(21, 8)); // retorna : 17
console.log(parseInt(021, 10)); // retorna : 17
console.log(parseInt(17, 8)); // retorna 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás especificando una raíz de octal, o base 8. En la base 8, 021 no es 21 ... ¡es 15!

Comment: ¿El resultado no seria 17?

Comment: Como comenta @Shaz el 0 al inicio indica que es de una raíz Octal.